# Anaconda Jypiter wont start, Spyder reporting errors

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, spyder

I did try uninstalling and installing Anaconda, but the problem remains the same.
Windows 10 x64, latest Anaconda
Installation goes fine, but when I start Spyder it reports this:
"You have missing dependencies, nbconvert >=4.0": None. However, nbconvert is already installed.
It prompted me to install Kite, when I did it says Kite installation error.
When I try to launch jupyter lab I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py", line 5,
>   in  from jupyterlab.labapp import main File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py",
>   line 14, in  from jupyterlab_server import slugify,
>   WORKSPACE_EXTENSION File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server__init__.py",
>   line 4, in  from .app import LabServerApp File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py",
>   line 9, in  from .server import ServerApp File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py",
>   line 14, in  from notebook.base.handlers import ( File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py",
>   line 22, in  from tornado import web, gen, escape, httputil File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line
>   87, in  from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py",
>   line 32, in  from tornado.http1connection import
>   HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py",
>   line 34, in  from tornado import iostream File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py",
>   line 40, in  from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket,
>   _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults File "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py",
>   line 39, in 
>   _client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH) File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 589, in
>   create_default_context context.load_default_certs(purpose) File
>   "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 490, in
>   load_default_certs self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
>   File "C:\Users\Aleksandar\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 482, in
>   _load_windows_store_certs self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs) ssl.SSLError: nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4003)

Answer (score 2):

Found an error. It is caused by the certificates issued by Serbian government. The solution is changing ssl.py like this:

```
def _load_windows_store_certs(self, storename, purpose):
certs = bytearray()
try:
    for cert, encoding, trust in enum_certificates(storename):
        # CA certs are never PKCS#7 encoded
        if encoding == "x509_asn":
            if trust is True or purpose.oid in trust:
                if "MUP Republike Srbije" not in str(cert): 
                    certs.extend(cert)
except PermissionError:
    warnings.warn("unable to enumerate Windows certificate store")
if certs:
    self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
return certs`
```

Comment: This is still an issue! But your solution is still working. Thank you for sharing!